# How to write a char array returned by recv to a text file, and read back out into a char array

Tags: c++, windows, character-encoding, network-programming, text-files

I need to take a message from recv, write it to a text file, then be able to reproduce the message using the contents of the text file. If I just cast each character in the array to an unsigned char and write it to the text file will I be able to pull it back out in a usable format? Or do I have to do some kind of conversion before or after I write/read the file?

Comment: what programming language are we talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it will. Just make sure open your file in binary mode so the RTL doesn't mangle your message.

```
ofstream f("file.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
f.write(data, len);
f.close();
```

Later...

```
ifstream f("file.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
f.read(data, len);
f.close();
```